# Server-based Chat

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, silverlight

Described on this scheme ["Server Clients Scheme"](https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B1F8H42zGlhfNGJkYjI4ZWYtYTFiYy00MWY0LThiMmEtMTk4ZTgwMGQyYjRm&hl=en_GB)
I try to create a Silverlight / Server Application which has EventHandler/Triggers, which can do the following:

- Notice whether a message was sent to "it" (the server)
- Notice that the sent message is new "to all" "except" "the sender"
- Send "to all" ("except...") "new message can be downloaded" / or even the new messages

How could this be done by using:
ASP.NET and Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/BuildASilverlight2WebChat.aspx